# Drop role in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database, schema, role, sql-drop

I am trying to drop one of the role in my SQL Server database. I dropped all the members from the role and when i tried to drop role i got this error message:

```
Msg 15138, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
The database principal owns a schema in the database, and cannot be dropped.
```

Does anyone know why? I checked the Owned Schema and it only had check sign in its own name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot drop a database principal that owns a schema. You have to transfer the schema ownership to some other database principal or drop the schema before you can drop the database principal.

Answer (score 4):

15138 error is due to the user you are trying to delete owns a schema.

If you run the below query you will get the schema owned by the user.

```
USE DatabaseName; 
SELECT s.name
FROM sys.schemas s
WHERE s.principal_id = USER_ID('UserName');
```

Let us say it returns 'db_denydatareader' schema. Then you can assign 
that schema to default user 'dbo' using the below query.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::db_denydatareader TO dbo;
```